# How do I get the 2nd h2 element in Go

Tags: go, web-scraping, html-parsing

I am having an issue locating the second h2 element to appear on a page I am locating the first one perfectly fine, but I am not sure how to get the second one. I am not sure if I can use attributes like `class=""` to help me, so I am not sure if I can add that and I am just unaware.

Here are the 2 h2 elements in the HTML that are relevant here:

```
<h2><a class="white" href="/department/men/">SHOP MEN'S DEPARTMENT</a></h2>

// Somewhere down below vv

<h2 class="indentlr notranslate" itemprop="name">Space Hippie 04 Volt Mens Running Shoe (Grey/Black/Volt/Ice Blue) Free Shipping</h2>
```

I want to print the text in between the second h2 tag: Space Hippie 04 Volt Mens Running Shoe (Grey/Black/Volt/Ice Blue) Free Shipping

Here is my code:

```
      // Previous request

if res.StatusCode >= 200 && res.StatusCode <= 299 {
        dataInBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

        pageContent := string(dataInBytes)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // Find a substr
        h2Index := strings.Index(pageContent, "<h2>")
        if h2Index == -1 {
            fmt.Println("No title element found")
            os.Exit(0)
        }

        h2Index += 7

        h2EndIndex := strings.Index(pageContent, "</h2>")
        if h2EndIndex == -1 {
            fmt.Println("No closing tag for title found.")
            os.Exit(0)
        }

        pageTitle := []byte(pageContent[h2Index:h2EndIndex])

        fmt.Printf("Page title: %s\n", pageTitle) // Prints the <a> tags in between the first h2  (<a class="white" href="/department/men/">SHOP MEN'S DEPARTMENT</a>)
}
```

Comment: String search is a very fragile way of parsing html. Try [golang.org/x/net/html](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html) instead.

Comment: could you give me an example of using that, in my situation please ? :)

Comment: There are examples in the docs.

Comment: I am not understanding it very well